# Minimal setup a raspi with archlinux

Tags: linux, ssh, arch-linux, raspberry-pi

I am about to setup my raspi with archlinux, and I would hope to use a minimal method. Ideally, I vision that I can connect the SD card to my laptop, do some burning and setting, and plug that into my raspi. After booting the raspi, it should be listening to SSH connection. I can then connect it from my laptop using SSH.

Is the above possible? I have read through lots of tutorials, but most of them require cable or more steps.. any pointers will be highly appreciated. Thank you very much!

Comment: ArchLinuxARM provides rootfs tarballs instead of image. Basically you just partition and format the card and extract files to it. It has sshd enabled out of the box.

Comment: You mean I install archlinuxarm as normal into an SSD, plug SSD into my raspi, power on, and ssd will be turned on automatically?

Comment: Archwiki is your friend here. You want to install it onto a USB (or SD-card in your case, boils down to the same): [Arch on USB](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Installing_Arch_Linux_on_a_USB_key). Once done put your SD-card in the raspi. Maybe preconfigure WiFi and ssh by booting into the SD-media from your PC before.

Comment: Well, what do you mean by install archlinuxarm *as normal*? Note that ArchLinuxARM isn't exactly the same as ArchLinux.

Comment: And did you actually mean (micro)SD or SSD (in a USB enclosure)? Preparing a USB drive instead of an SD card (i.e. that you are going to use with the built-in slot) requires you to change the fstab and maybe even the bootloader config.

Comment: @Fiximan won't be his friend for this coz it's (ArchLinux)ARM...